# The reasoning behind $\sup\{\alpha\beta+\alpha\zeta\mid\zeta<\gamma\}=\alpha\beta+\sup\{\alpha\zeta\mid\zeta<\gamma\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum, ordinals, well-orders

> Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be ordinals. Then $\alpha(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma$.

I'm been looking for some proofs of this theorem on MSE and found that the gist is the equality $\sup\{\alpha\beta+\alpha\zeta\mid\zeta<\gamma\}=\alpha\beta+\sup\{\alpha\zeta\mid\zeta<\gamma\}$. How do I take $\alpha\beta$ out of the $\sup$?

Please help me elaborate on how we get this equality! Thank you so much! For reference, I include the proof also.

---

**Proof:**

We prove the statement by induction on $\gamma$.

- If $\gamma=0$, then $\alpha(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha(\beta)=\alpha\beta=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma$.
- If $\gamma=\delta+1$, then by IH, $\alpha(\beta+\delta)=\alpha\beta+\alpha\delta$. We have $\alpha(\beta+(\delta+1))=\alpha((\beta+\delta)+1)$ $=\alpha(\beta+\delta)+\alpha=(\alpha\beta+\alpha\delta)+\alpha=\alpha\beta+(\alpha\delta+\alpha)=\alpha\beta+\alpha(\delta+1)$.
- If $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal, then $\beta+\gamma$ is a limit ordinal and thus $\beta+\gamma=\sup\{\beta+\zeta\mid\zeta<\gamma\}$. Then $\alpha(\beta+\gamma)=\sup\{\alpha\xi\mid\xi<\beta+\gamma\}=\sup\{\alpha(\beta+\zeta)\mid\zeta<\gamma\}=\color{blue}{\sup\{\alpha\beta+\alpha\zeta\mid\zeta<\gamma\}=\alpha\beta+\sup\{\alpha\zeta\mid\zeta<\gamma\}}=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from a more general fact:

> Let $A$ be a set of ordinals and $\alpha$ be an ordinal. Then $$\alpha+\sup A=\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid \gamma\in A\}.\tag{1}$$

Note that by definition $\sup A=\bigcup A$. Let $\beta:=\sup A$.

- If $\beta=0$ then $(1)$ holds trivially.
- If $\beta=\delta+1$, you can show that necessarely $\beta\in A$, i.e, $\beta=\max A$. Therefore $(1)$ holds.
- If $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then by the very definition of ordinal addition, $\alpha+\beta=\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in\beta\}$, and you can easily verify that $$\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in\beta\}=\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}$$ by looking at the cases where $\beta\in A$ and $\beta\notin A$.

Comment: Hi! It seems to me that $\sup A=\sup\sup A$ is not correct. For example, take $A=\{0,1\}$, then $\sup A=1$ and thus $\sup\sup A=\sup 1=\sup\{0\}=0$. Clearly, $0\neq 1$. Please have a check!

Comment: Please have a check on my reasoning in the previous comment! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Akira You're right, sorry!  I'll modify my answer now.

Comment: @Akira Rectified. Thank you for yor remark!

Comment: Thank you so much! Honestly, I have failed to prove $\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in\beta\}=\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}$ after several attempts. Could you please leave me more specific hints to prove $\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in\beta\}=\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}$?

Comment: @Akira It's a pleasure :) Sure! This equality is for the case where $\beta=\sup A$ is a limit ordinal. There are two cases: either $\beta\in A$ or $\beta\notin A$. If $\beta\in A$, then clearly $\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}=\alpha+\beta$, can you see it? But $\alpha+\beta=\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in\beta\}$ by definition of addition for limit ordinals.

Comment: Now, if $\beta\notin A$, then every element of $A$ is an element of $\beta$, hence $\sup\{alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}\le\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in\beta\}$. On the other hand, take $\gamma\in\beta$. Since $\gamma<\beta=\sup A$, you can find $\delta\in A$ such that $\gamma<\delta$. Hence $\forall\gamma\in\beta,\exists\delta\in A,\alpha+\gamma<\alpha+\delta$. This shows that $\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in\beta\}\le\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}$.

Comment: Please check whether my reasoning is correct or not! 1. $\beta\notin A\implies\beta$ is a limit ordinal: Assume $\gamma'<\beta=\sup A$, then $\gamma'<\gamma_1$ for some $\gamma_1\in A$. Since $\sup A\notin A$, there is $\gamma_2\in A$ such that $\gamma_1<\gamma_2$. It follows that $\gamma'+1\le\gamma_1<\gamma_2\le\beta$ and thus $\gamma'+1<\beta$. [...]

Comment: […] 2. $\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}=\alpha+\beta$: 2A. $\forall\gamma\in A:\gamma\le\sup A=\beta\implies\forall\gamma\in A:\alpha+\gamma\le\alpha+\beta$ $\implies\alpha+\beta$ is an upper bound of $\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}$. 2B. Assume $\theta$ is an upper bound of $\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}$, then $\forall\gamma\in A:\alpha+\gamma\le\theta$. Since $\beta\in A$, $\alpha+\beta\le\theta$. From 2A and 2B, $\alpha+\beta$ is the supremum of $\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}$, or equivalently $\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}=\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: Well done! 2. is correct. As for 1., you reached a result that is true for any limit ordinal $\lambda$, namely $\forall\gamma\in\lambda,\gamma+1\in\lambda$. Thisis actually the very definition of a limit ordinal. I can't see how this makes you reach the desired conclusion. To prove that $\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}=\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in\beta\}$ for the case $\beta\notin A$, use the indications I gave in an earlier comment.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. Actually, in (1), I prove an unrelated theorem, i.e. $\beta=\sup A\notin A\implies\beta$ is a limit ordinal. Of course, in case $\beta\notin A$, we can easily prove that $\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma\in A\}=\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: @Akira Ah alright I see. That's a good result !!

Comment: Hi! I would like to ask my final question if my proof in (1) is correct?

Comment: @Akira Hi! Yes it is correct! Well done!

Comment: @Akira Ganbatte for your studies! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated and persistent help ^^ You made my day!

Comment: @Akira It's a pleasure :) 喜んで ;)